# What is the equivalent System.DirectoryServices.Protocols code for updating an AD computer?

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

This PowerShell code correctly updates the description attribute of an AD computer:

```ps1
$comp = Get-ADComputer -Server $server -Filter "Name -eq 'example'" -Properties Description,MemberOf,Location,CanonicalName
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $adUser, (ConvertTo-SecureString $adPass -AsPlainText -Force)
Set-ADComputer $comp -Description "Test" -Credential $creds -Server $server -Confirm:$false
```

What is the equivalent System.DirectoryServices.Protocols code? My attempt at it produces the error:

```
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: The user has insufficient access rights. 00002098: SecErr: DSID-031514A0, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS)
```

despite successfully authenticating using the same credentials, dc, etc:

```csharp
var dn = entity.DistinguishedName;
var mod = new ModifyRequest(dn, DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace, "description", "Test");
//mod.Controls.Add(new PermissiveModifyControl());
conn.SendRequest(mod);
```

Is this doable using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols or should I switch to some other library?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code and get the idea of how to do it in Powershell or just use it.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FreeLDAP/1.0.0.0/Content/Set-LdapUser.ps1

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the example code in the link is how I was originally doing it (manually creating DirectoryAttributeModifications rather than relying on the ModifyRequest constructor). But I think your answer heads in the right direction. I'm still hoping to find some example code out there that shows how to modify a computer successfully using the Protocols lib rather than PS Set-ADComputer or using a ComputerPrincipal from the AccountManagement lib (supposedly slow, so I've been trying to steer clear).